# Optimizing function to compare every value in array to each other

Tags: python, tensorflow, math, optimization

I'm using tensorflow for some machine learning, and I need to do some transformations to the data beforehand. The bottleneck I'm running into is my function to take an array of numbers and compare every number to every other number and create a table of those comparisons.

The function is the following:

```
def compare(list, length):
    result = np.zeros(length*length)
    i=0
    for row in range(length):
        for col in range(length):
            if row != col:
              result[i] = list[col] - list[row]
            else:
              result[i] = list[row]
            i = i + 1
    return result.reshape((length,length))
```

It is painfully slow, is there any way to utilize my GPU to achieve this same result? Or at least optimize this function to perform faster?

The idea is that is would take a list of numbers like

`0 1 2 3 4 5`

and generate a comparison table with the difference of the column and row, except in the case that the value is compared to itself, in which case it would simply return itself.

```
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]
 [-1.  1.  1.  2.  3.  4.]
 [-2. -1.  2.  1.  2.  3.]
 [-3. -2. -1.  3.  1.  2.]
 [-4. -3. -2. -1.  4.  1.]
 [-5. -4. -3. -2. -1.  5.]]
```

I've attempted to use @jit, but the results seem strangely slow

```
@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def compare2(list, length):
    result = np.zeros(length*length)
    i=0
    for row in range(length):
        for col in range(length):
            if row != col:
              result[i] = list[col] - list[row]
            else:
              result[i] = list[row]
            i = i + 1
    return result.reshape((length,length))
```

yields the following result on a list of ~300 items:

```
compare: Elapsed time is 0.062655 seconds.
compare2: Elapsed time is 0.423727 seconds.
```

**EDIT:**

I'm using the compare function inside of another loop to generate a list of tables. I combined those into one function, and now @jit does outperform the original function by 15x.

Comment: Might be useful to have a look at numba: http://numba.pydata.org/ to perhaps parallelize the loops and compile python code to machine code for more speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python loop is very slow. Numpy functions mostly written on c and work much faster.

```
import numpy as np



def compare(list, length):
    """
    >>> print(compare([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 6))
    [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
     [-1  1  1  2  3  4]
     [-2 -1  2  1  2  3]
     [-3 -2 -1  3  1  2]
     [-4 -3 -2 -1  4  1]
     [-5 -4 -3 -2 -1  5]]
    """
    return np.diag(list) - np.subtract.outer(list, list)
```

Comment: Incredible. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the Comparison algorithm it seems that it is optimised only as since you have to create a comparison table matrix of n*n (n = size of list). So, you need total n^2 records . It means Time complexity  is fair enough.

Now coming to next point that how you can do it using GPU?

- you can use "cudf" Library

## cuDF

This is same as "Panda" but dedicated for GPU operations and like mirror of "Panda" on GPU. You just need to convert "Panda" Dataframe to "cudf" dataframe like shown below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cudf

pandas_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(0, 100000000, size=100000000),
                          'b': np.random.randint(0, 100000000, size=100000000)})
                          
cudf_df = cudf.DataFrame.from_pandas(pandas_df)
```

Now, see the difference below:

```
# Timing Pandas
# Output: 82.2 ms per loop
%timeit pandas_df.a.mean()

# Timing cuDF
# Output: 5.12 ms per loop
%timeit cudf_df.a.mean()

# Timing Pandas
# Output: 39.2 s per loop
%timeit pandas_df.merge(pandas_df, on='b')

# Timing cuDF
# Output: 2.76 s per loop
%timeit cudf_df.merge(cudf_df, on='b')
```

For More details Refer : https://towardsdatascience.com/heres-how-you-can-speedup-pandas-with-cudf-and-gpus-9ddc1716d5f2